# Accurately count number of links in PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, regex

I have a form that I am validating with JS on the front-end and PHP on the server side. What I need is a way to reliably count the number of links in an HTML string. The best way that I could think of was to count the closing  tags. However simply searching for this tag will not work because the user could circumvent the validation by adding spaces like so: `</a   >`.

I am fairly new to regex and this is the pattern that I have been able to come up with so far:

```
<[ \n\t]*\/[ \n\t]*a[ \n\t]*>
```

In Javascript:

```
function link_count(s){
    return s.match(/<[ \n\t]*\/[ \n\t]*a[ \n\t]*>/g, s).length;
}
```

In PHP:

```
function count_links($str){
    return preg_match_all('<[ \n\t]*/[ \n\t]*a[ \n\t]*>', $str, $matches);
}
```

Is this the best approach? Will it affect the performance of my form (the html string could be very long)? I am looking for the most efficient and reliable solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A sample of the string you are trying to regex would be very useful

Comment: regex is not a good way to parse html, but it will probably work for what you're doing. that said, not all `a` tags are links - maybe try looking for the strings `href="` and `href='`

Comment: regexp is fine for some/most html: it's recursive repeating tags that blow it's mind. since <A> doesn't nest, regexp would be fine.  you should be able to search for /<\/a\b/, because anything else after that won't be an anchor tag

Comment: I feel this MUST be linked...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: i purposely don't link that on every regex html question. regex will work just fine in many simple cases where people want to parse html (such as this one) - i do it all the time for quick tasks like this. there's nothing wrong with it, as long as you know the limitations.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. Like I said, I am pretty new to regex so I don't know all its pros and cons yet.

Answer (score 0):

So, like @sgroves said, `</a>` are not all links. checking for `href` might be more interesting.
Also, why not checking the opening tag directly? 
I tried searching for `<a .... href>`

You might use the 's' modifier to ignore newlines...

`/<\s*\ba\b.*?href/gs`

http://regex101.com/r/bG8lN1/3

Comment: `[\w\W\s]` seems... odd. "Anything that is a word character or not a word character or a space"...

Comment: Right, I didn't realize I ended up with that. At this point, with the ungreedy operator, we could change that for `.*`. I will update.

Comment: Does \s take care of all the white space characters? When I press enter after '<a' in my textarea the link is not counted.